# retrieve another users posts shared by followeds sql, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this arrangement:

I want to retrieve all the posts shared by followeds, bearing in mind those shared posts doesnt belong to another followeds or the main follower.

**TABLE USERS**

```
id_user | name
15      Joe
16       Dan
17       Tom
```

**TABLE COMMUNITY**

```
id_follower | followed  
15              16
15              17
```

**TABLE POSTS**

```
id_post | id_user | post    
    1       15          hi1     
    2       16          hi2    
    3       15          hi3   
    4       17          hi4      
    5       15          hi5   
    6       16          hi6   
    7       17          hi7  
    8       18          hi8   
    9       14          hi9
```

I'm adding up a new table "shares".

**TABLE SHARES**

```
id_sharer | id_post
16        4     
14        8 
17        8       
16        9
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT POSTS**

```
17        8  hi7 (shared by Tom)    
16        9  hi6  (shared by Dan)
```

How shouldit be the sql query to get this new arrangement?

I was thinking adding a line `LEFT JOIN shares l ON l.id_sharer=p.id_user`

```
SELECT p.*,
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id_user=c.id_followed
LEFT JOIN shares l ON l.id_sharer=c.id_followed
LEFT JOIN community c ON c.id_follower=p.id_user
WHERE p.id_user=15
ORDER BY p.date_post DESC
```

*Tested but not retrieve as expected

Comment: ........anyone?

Comment: It's confusing that you seem to have the date_like and the date_post in the same column. It might help to have some clarification of what you are trying to do in your sample output.  For example, likes to posts is probably a many to one relationship. Are you trying to show all of the likes on the same line?

Comment: ok. Yes I want to show date_like & date_post in the same column, and order the results according to that. When no likes then no date_like in this column. It doesnt matter the number of likes a post has. the most important is to how to get this? `to show date_like & date_post in the same column? `

Comment: And if there are multiple likes do you only want the most recent one? Or do you want each of them?

Comment: the most recent one. I think you are getting to the point. thank you.

Comment: this is to show the more recent activity only. I think the point would be: filling this date column with date_post and higher date_like, then ordering by  `l.date_like as date` and  `l.date_post as date`....

Comment: I posted a query for you in the answers section, please give it a try and see if we are getting closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: ok. thank you. this is going to take a little but I'll let you know. this is the approach I was expecting ... `IF(l.date_like IS NOT NULL, l.date_like, p.date_post) AS date`, but a doubt I have is, do this get the higher (l.date_like)?

Comment: That's what the ORDER BY l.date_like DESC does. It orders before the GROUP BY throws out duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first crack at this for you:

```
SELECT p.id_post, p.id_user, p.post, IF(l.date_like IS NOT NULL, l.date_like, p.date_post) AS date, l.id_liker
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.id_post = p.id_post
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id_user = l.id_liker
ORDER BY l.date_like DESC
GROUP BY p.id_post
```

As a quick walk through of how I am approaching the problem, first I am LEFT JOINing the likes and ordering them in descending order, just as you did. Then I am grouping on the post id in order to ensure I only get one line per post. Then in the selector I am checking to see if the like date is null and substituting in the date of the post instead of the most recent like if there are no likes.

UPDATE

This should add the logic to ensure that only the likes of followers will count. Since one probably cannot follow themselves this should also keep one's own likes from affecting position.

```
SELECT p.id_post, p.id_user, p.post, IF(l.date_like IS NOT NULL, l.date_like, p.date_post) AS date, l.id_liker
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.id_post = p.id_post
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id_user = l.id_liker
LEFT JOIN community c ON l.id_liker = c.followed
WHERE c.id_follower = 15
ORDER BY l.date_like DESC, p.date_post DESC
GROUP BY p.id_post
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this out. I needed to add `ORDER BY l.date_like DESC ,p.date_post DESC` to make it work as expected. The first approach it works, thank you by that...Ok, then there is this problem, when I, as a user (id_user=15) like any post (I'm not a followed) the results rearrange making this post getting date_like and getting to the top, it is supposed that as I'm not a followed, the post must remain in the same position after being liked by me.

Comment: So to clarify, if I am looking at a feed of posts and someone that I do not follow likes something, their like should not affect the order of the posts I see. Is that correct?

Comment: I updated the answer to fit that parameter. Let me know if it works.

Comment: looks promising, but it doesnt retrieve as expected.

Comment: I think this is line is the key.  `IF(l.date_like IS NOT NULL, l.date_like, p.date_post) AS date`

Comment: After several tries, I got the expected output (updated on question), the problem is the query need optimization since I had to make use of a subquery, I would be pleased if you could check it and give me your opinion. thnak you.

Comment: Congratulations on getting something returned that works! I agree we can probably do this without the subquery, but we are very close. It's just a matter of thinking through how SQL works this. When you join a table it is like you join all of the rows to each other, then use the ON statement to filter out the joined rows you don't want. You can achieve similar ends in the where clause. Since we have aggregation in the MAX() we can create more rows than we want and throw the rest away.  All that to say, you can do this in the where clause without a subquery.

Comment: So, remove 
AND l.id_liker  IN (SELECT d.id_followed FROM community d WHERE d.id_follower = '15') 
and alter the WHERE clause to
WHERE c.id_follower=15 AND c.id_followed=l.id_liker

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `'TABLE POSTS'.'id_user'` is the author of the post and matches to `'TABLE USERS'.'id_user'` and that you want to see the Posts that have Entries in `'TABLE LIKES'` first and then all the others.
So I suggest to the following `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`

```
select p.*, l.date_like, u.* from posts p 
left join likes l on p.id_post=l.id_post
left join users u on l.id_liker=u.id_user
order by l.date_like desc, p.date_post desc
```